# ElasticSearch - Ordering exact before partial matches?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having with ordering the exact string matches before it renders the partial matches in ElasticSearch

Let's say I have three documents:

- Michael A
- Michael B
- Micha

If I do a search for **micha**, it only returns the third document. If however I search for **micha***, I get all three of the documents, in the order I've listed above.

My question is, how do I get the third document, the exact match, to show up in prior to the other results?

```
  :analysis => {
      :filter => {
        "my_edge_ngram_filter" => {
          "type"     => "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram" => 1,
          "max_gram" => 128,
          "side" => "front",
        },
        "my_phone_filter" => {
          "type"    => "pattern_replace",
          "pattern" => "\\D",
          "replacement" => ""
        }
      },
      :analyzer => {
        "default_index" => {
          "tokenizer" => "uax_url_email",
          "filter" => [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "stop",
            "my_edge_ngram_filter"
          ],
          "type"   => "custom"
        },
        "my_phone_analyzer" => {
          "tokenizer" => "keyword",
          "filter" => [
            "my_phone_filter",
          ],
          "type"   => "custom"
        },
        "default_search" => {
          "type"   => "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the query you're making to your question? It's not clear what fields you're querying and how.

Answer (score 3):

You can use multi_field + boosting:

- one is mapping with search by words and boost it with score higher than the second field
- second is mapping with your ngram analyzer.

> ```
> "name" : {
>       "type" : "multi_field",
>       "fields" : {
>           "name" : {
>               "type" : "string",
>               "index" : "analyzed",
>               "index_analyzer" : "standard",
>               "search_analyzer" : "standard",
>               "boost" : 10.0
>           },
>           "partial": {
>               "type" : "string",
>               "index" : "analyzed",
>               "index_analyzer" : "your_ngram_analyzer",
>               "search_analyzer" : "standard",
>               "boost" : 1.0
>           }
>   }
>    }
> ```

Then do a search on both field, ex:

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "micha",
      "fields": [
        "name.partial",
        "name"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
```

PS: You can also specify field boosting inside query dynamically, e.g.:

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "micha",
      "fields": [
        "name.partial^1",
        "name^10"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
```